# Select statement for sql server

Tags: sql-server

Hello I need to get two types of values from a column, the statement should display as follow,

```
Select bid-id 
from bid 
where status = 'Expired'
```

as `Successful` and

```
Select bid-id 
from bid 
where status ='Unsold'
```

as `Failed`, each one ordered by `datename(mm, date)`.

Can someone help me how to make these two statements run in one same statement please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
[bid-id],
CASE WHEN Status = 'Expired' THEN
    'Successful'
WHEN Status = 'Unsold' THEN
    'Failed'
END AS [Status]
FROM
    [bid]
ORDER BY datename(mm, date)
```

If you need values in separate columns, use this:

```
SELECT
(SELECT [Bid-id] FROM [bid] WHERE Status = 'Expired' ORDER BY datename(mm, date)) AS [Successful],
(SELECT [Bid-id] FROM [bid] WHERE Status = 'Unsold' ORDER BY datename(mm, date)) AS [Failed]
FROM
[Bid]
```

Comment: Hello the value is being displaying into a column name status, i don't need that, i need that the successful and failed are display in an individual column each as result can you check please

Comment: @user3287068 Have you tried spending more than 1 second yourself? Or learning sql at one point? should Ashishek write your program, too?